# H2O - Not seeing much speed-up after moving to powerful machine

Tags: h2o

I am running a Python program that calls H2O for deep learning (training and testing). The program runs in a loop of 20 iterations and in each loop calls `H2ODeepLearningEstimator()` 4 times and associated `predict()` and `model_performance()`. I am doing `h2o.remove_all()` and cleaning up all data-related Python objects after each iteration.

Data size: training set 80,000 with 122 features (all float) with 20% for validation (10-fold CV). test set 20,000. Doing binary classification.

Machine 1: Windows 7, 4 core, Xeon, each core 3.5GHz, Memory 32 GB
Takes about 24 hours to complete

Machine 2: CentOS 7, 20 core, Xeon, each core 2.0GHz, Memory 128 GB
Takes about 17 hours to complete
I am using h2o.init(nthreads=-1, max_mem_size = 96)

So, the speed-up is not that much.
My questions:
 1) Is the speed-up typical?
 2) What can I do to achieve substantial speed-up?
        2.1) Will adding more cores help?
        2.2) Are there any H2O configuration or tips that I am missing?

Thanks very much.
- Mohammad,
  Graduate student

Answer (score 2):

If the training time is the main effort, and you have enough memory, then the speed up will be proportional to cores times core-speed. So, you might have expected a 40/14 = 2.85 speed-up (i.e. your 24hrs coming down to the 8-10 hour range).

There is a typo in your h2o.init(): `96` should be `"96g"`. However, I think that was a typo when writing the question, as `h2o.init()` would return an error message. (And H2O would fail to start if you'd tried `"96"`, with the quotes but without the "g".)

You didn't show your `h2o.deeplearning()` command, but I am guessing you are using early stopping. And that can be unpredictable. So, what might have happened is that your first 24hr run did, say, 1000 epochs, but your second 17hr run did 2000 epochs. (1000 vs. 2000 would be quite an extreme difference, though.)

It might be that you are spending too much time scoring. If you've not touched the defaults, this is unlikely. But you could experiment with `train_samples_per_iteration` (e.g. set it to 10 times the number of your training rows).

> What can I do to achieve substantial speed-up?

Stop using cross-validation. That might be a bit controversial, but personally I think 80,000 training rows is going to be enough to do an 80%/10%/10% split into train/valid/test. That will be 5-10 times quicker.

If it is for a paper, and you want to show more confidence in the results, once you have your final model, and you've checked that test score is close to valid score, then rebuild it a couple of times using a different seed for the 80/10/10 split, and confirm you end up with the same metrics. (*)

*: By the way, take a look at the score for each of the 10 cv models you've already made; if they are fairly close to each other, then this approach should work well. If they are all over the place, you might have to re-consider the train/valid/test splits - or just think about what it is in your data that might be causing that sensitivity.